# Abrir formulario dinamico una sola vez

Tags: jquery

Tengo el codigo html para crear un ticket o factura de venta. Y deseo añadir todos los cheques que se deseen como forma de pago.
Para esto tengo un boton nuevo cheque que carga dinamicamente un formulario con los datos del mismo y un boton de registrar.
Pero el problema es si hago click mas de una vez aparece nuevamente otro form indefinidamente. La idea es que hasta que no se cargue un cheque que no aparezca otro formulario, osea de a uno por vez.

```
<div class="row"> 
  <a id="nuevocheque" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new"></span>Nuevo Cheque
  </a>
</div>

<div id="datoscheque"></div>
```

Y en factura.js:

```
$("#nuevocheque").click(function(){
   var formcheque='<div class="row"><label  class="col-sm-2 control- 
   label">BANCO</label><div class="col-sm-4">'+'<select id="bancos"><option 
   value"=0">Seleccione<option></select></div>'+'<label class="col-sm-2 control- 
   label">CUENTA N°</label>'+'<div class="col-sm-4">'+'<input type="text" 
   class="form-control" id="nrocuenta" placeholder="Cuenta 
   Bancaria"/>'+'</div>'+'<label class="col-sm-2 control- 
   label">Titular</label>'+'<div class="col-sm-4">'+'<input type="text" 
   class="form-control" id="titular" placeholder="Titular"/>'+'</div>'+' <label 
   class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha de Cobro</label>'+'<div class="col-sm- 
   4">'+'<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechacobro" 
   placeholder="Deposito el:"/>'+'</div>'+'<label class="col-sm-2 control- 
   label">Importe</label>'+'<div class="col-sm-4">'+'<input type="text" 
   class="form-control" id="Importe" placeholder="Son pesos"/>'+'</div>'+'<div 
   class="row"> <a id="acreditar" class="btn btn-primary">'+'<span 
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Ingresar al pago</a></div></div>';

   $(formcheque).appendTo("#datoscheque");
      listarbancos();

   $("#acreditar").click(function(){
      var Importe=$("#Importe").val();
      $("#cheques").val(Importe);
    });
});
```

De que manera puedo lograrlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una buena opción es utilizar la función **[one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** de `jQuery`, *el cual sirve para ejecutar sólo una vez al elemento asignado*

```js
$("#nuevocheque").one('click', function(){
   var formcheque='<div class="row"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">BANCO</label><div class="col-sm-4"><select id="bancos"><option value"=0">Seleccione<option></select></div><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">CUENTA N°</label><div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nrocuenta" placeholder="Cuenta Bancaria"/></div><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titular</label><div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="titular" placeholder="Titular"/></div><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha de Cobro</label><div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechacobro" placeholder="Deposito el:"/></div><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importe</label><div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Importe" placeholder="Son pesos"/></div><div class="row"><a id="acreditar" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Ingresar al pago</a></div></div>';

   $(formcheque).appendTo("#datoscheque");
      listarbancos();

   $("#acreditar").click(function(){
      var Importe=$("#Importe").val();
      $("#cheques").val(Importe);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="row"> 
  <a id="nuevocheque" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new"></span>Nuevo Cheque
  </a>
</div>

<div id="datoscheque"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*También edite la forma en que estabas creando el formulario, ya que estabas concatenando cada elemento de tu formulario. En este caso es innecesario ya que no estas concantenando variables de ningún tipo.*

Nos cuentas colega =)

Comment: Funciono para que se muestre una sola vez, pero una compra puede tener varios cheques asociados, entonces borro los campos del form, porque si lo oculto despues no se vuelve a mostrar, pero me sirve igual